# Trying to create a database but getting error "Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0"

Tags: mysql, sql, datagrip

I am very new to DataGrip and SQL in general, so please be kind.

I want to create a simple MySQL database for my homemade project.
So, open datagrip --> create new datasource --> mysql

Tried "Test connection" but it keeps giving me the same error.

What i am doing wrong? I need to set something first?

[image: error on the creation of the page]

Comment: Do you have MySQL installed, is it running and listening on port 3306 of localhost? See also [Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql) and its duplicate.

Comment: Seems that there is no established server. DataGrip is only a client, it does not create the database itslef.

Comment: thanks to you both, now its working!

Answer (score 0):

DataGrip can't create MySQL database. IDE just can establish a connection to existent server (or local instance).